# Trying to only allow swipe behavior on a single specific row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swipe

I am using the latest Swift 3 Beta (Xcode Version 8.0 beta 6 (8S201h)).

I have read that you need the last three funcs to implement the swipe behavior and that is working correctly as I can swipe on all of the rows.

The basic behavior of my table is that I display between one and eight rows (numberOfRowsInSection) of show results.  The user can tap any row and an 'Expanded'/Detail row will be inserted (didSelectRowAt) below the taped cell.

When the user swipes the 'Expanded' row, there are two buttons that are revealed (editActionsForRowAtIndexPath).

### ISSUE

The user can still swipe any of the other rows, this is what I am trying to eliminate with the logic in (canEditRowAt indexPath).

I have tested returning both false and true and the action still works.  I also included the print line to see if the func is being called and it never shows up in the log.

Thoughts?

```
import UIKit

class vcAwards: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

... lots of other working code ...

/************************/
/** List Award Winners **/
/************************/
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return award.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // TBD add isExpanded to Award Class????
    let tappedRow = indexPath.row
    let nextRow   = indexPath.row + 1

    if expandedRowIs == -1 {
        award.insert("Expanded", at: nextRow)
        expandedRowIs = tappedRow
    } else if tappedRow == expandedRowIs || tappedRow == expandedRowIs + 1 {
        award.remove(at: expandedRowIs + 1)
        expandedRowIs = -1
    } else {
        award.remove(at: expandedRowIs + 1)
        if tappedRow > expandedRowIs {
            award.insert("Expanded", at: tappedRow)
            expandedRowIs = tappedRow - 1
        } else {
            award.insert("Expanded", at: nextRow)
            expandedRowIs = tappedRow
        }
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { ... }

///
/// Next three functions provide for the Swipe left functionality
///
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {
    if award[indexPath.row] != "Expanded" {
        return nil
    } else {
        let myDog = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "My Dog") { action, index in
            print("'My Dog' swipped and clicked")
        }
        myDog.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange

        let share = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Share") { action, index in
            print("'Share' swipped and clicked")
        }
        share.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

        return [share, myDog]
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {

    // ---> This print never shows up in the log
    print ("*** Want to only swipe on Expanded rows: \(award[indexPath.row])")

    // ---> What I want to use as the final logic
    //  return award[indexPath.row] == "Expanded"

    // ---> Using either of the following allow the swipes to happen
    //return true
    return false
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
}
}
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `award[indexPath.row] == "Expanded"`?

Comment: That should be return award[canEditRowAtindexPath.row] == "Expanded", but it did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Simply return `nil` in `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath` and `false` in `canEditRowAtIndexPath` for the rows you don't want to apply the actions.

Comment: That almost works, now I do not get the custom buttons, just the 'Delete 'button for the non-Expanded rows.  In canEditRowAtindexPath both return true and return false allow the swiping.

Comment: No, you need to apply the same filter in `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath` **and** `canEditRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: I am not understanding.  (I updated the original code to include an if / else in editActionsForRowAtIndexPath).  What do I need to include in canEditRowAtIndexPath?  Everything that I have tried does not work (true, false & row == expanded row).

Comment: I found the issue, a typo in the func.  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {} and I had func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {.  I have updated the code.  thanx!

Answer (score 0):

I had two issues in the original code.  I was not returning nil for the cells that I did not want custom actions on and I did not have the correct option name.

Corrected in the initial code sample:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
```

Was incorrect:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
```